# What is the pdf of sum of log-normal and normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

The question goes like this:
$Z = X+Y$; where

$X$ is Log-normal Random variable with parameters - $\mu = 0 \quad \sigma^2= 1$,

$Y$ is Gaussian Random variable with $\mu= 0\quad \sigma^2= 1$

What is the pdf of $Z$?
I know it will be the convolution of $X$ and $Y$. However, I am unable to solve it. Is it even solvable?

PS: $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Are we assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have difficulty finding an analytical solution given that the characteristic function $$\varphi_X(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(it)^n}{n!}e^{\frac 12 n^2} $$ does not converge.

Comment: Yes, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By saying `convolution`, you mean the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and the joint probability density function of them can be represented as the convolution of their `pdf`s.

Let $X$ be the log-normal random variable, and $Y$ the normal one, the `pdf`'s of which are as below in the figure.

The probability density function of $Z=X+Y$ cannot be represented in closed form, but the numerical results of the `pdf` $f_Z(x)$ can be evaluated by numerical integral.

$$f_Z(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(t)\cdot f_Y(x-t){\rm{d}}t=\int_{t=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}\left( (t-x)^2+{\ln^2t}\right)}}{2\pi t}{\rm{d}}t$$

So a better way to answer this question might be to visualize them as below:

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to know the expression for $f_Z$$(x)$ by any means? Can I know the tool used for performing numerical integration and getting the graph above?

Comment: hi @skt9, the analytical expression for $f_Z(x)$ has been given as above. There are a lot of special functions which have no closed forms (expression by elementary functions) but can be numerically obtained or visualized easily. -- A powerful tool in calculating the numerical integral and visualizing the profile is [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), which is also what I was using in getting the graph here.